# apple-app-site-association file is not fetched from server but cached at apple?

Tags: ios, branch.io, ios-universal-links, applinks, apple-app-site-associate

We have universal links working for a long time now. Today I added a path to the AASA file (let's call it sub2). The path was not recognised by the app, even after reinstalling it.

When I debugged I noticed the file is being fetched by the applinks service, but the request is not entering our server. The service does get the old AASA file, so it *seems* like apple's CDN is caching this file.

Debugging:

- AASA file is valid: tested with [Branch Validator](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) as well as the new URL in [Apple's appsearch-validation-tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool)

  ```
  {
      "applinks": {
          "apps": [],
          "details": [
              {
                  "appID": "redacted",
                  "paths": [
                      "/main/*",
                      "/sub1/*",
                      "/sub2/*",
                      "/pagex-*"
                  ]
              }
          ]
      },
      "activitycontinuation": {
          "apps": [
              "redacted"
          ]
      }
  }
  ```

  ```
  Apple tool: tested https://redacteddomain/sub2/something
  Link to Application: Passed
  Universal true
  ...
  ```
- File is not cached at our side/Cloudflare: above validators confirm this but to be sure I also purged the cache
- Iphone console shows the AASA file is being fetched:

  `Beginning data task AASA-64DCD3xx-xxxxx { domain: xx….xx, bytes: 0, route: cdn }`
- Created a sysdiagnose file on the Iphone, it show the AASA file is fetched at this very timestamp but the contents is the old content:

  ```
  Service:              applinks
  App ID:               (redacted)
  App Version:          2.3.4
  App PI:               <LSPersistentIdentifier 0x101579cc0> { v = 0, t = 0x8, u = 0x11c0, db = 49C449xx-xxxx, {length = 8, bytes = 0xc011000000000000} }
  Domain:               (redacted)
  Patterns:             {"/":"/main/*"}, {"/":"/sub1/*"}, {"/":"/pagex*"}
  User Approval:        unspecified
  Site/Fmwk Approval:   approved
  Flags:                
  Last Checked:         2021-07-13 18:45:00 +0000
  Next Check:           2021-07-18 18:36:18 +0000
  ```

Is Apple effectively caching the file, is this because we provided wrong cache headers? How to test their CDN, are these urls public or can I find them back in the logs? Is there a way to force a purge at their side?

**UPDATE**:
Found out we can directly query the CDN using the url https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/yourdomain.com

=> This request returns the OLD file, while the original file (as mentioned in the Apple-From header) is newer!
According to the Age header the file is however only minutes old..

**UPDATE2**:
The issue is finally resolved, I can only guess the CDN cache refreshed now. I've made sure our server now sends a Cache-Control: no-store header, it seems this makes the Apple CDN cache it for one hour (max-age: 3600) now but after that hour it is effectively refreshed.

Note that before the sudden solution, the CDN returned a file with age of only a few minutes and a max-age of 1800 so it is still very unclear to me why it was not serving the new content 40 hours after the server file was updated.

At least for people with similar issues in the future, the CDN url is a very good starting point to debug: https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/yourdomain.com

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10098/?time=879 ?

Comment: thanks @matt that answers my first question. As the problem still persists, the other questions remain.. how long is this cached, how to check, prevent, update

Comment: Well did you switch to developer mode as the video says?

Comment: No, as that would not solve the production issue, right?

Comment: Yeah I have no idea. Need to poke the cache somehow...? But do try it and see

Comment: I am wondering whether I could get the IP range for the Apple CDN servers so that I can whitelist it when it tries to hit my test environment. any thoughts?

Comment: The CDN checks your server every 24h, the device checks the CDN every week. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

Comment: This URL:  https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/yourdomain.com
does not seem to return anything - just blank screen.

Comment: @AleksandarVacić you'll have to substitute yourdomain.com with your domain name

Comment: I figured that out :) but it still returned blank screen. But that actually means that CDN can't access the AASA file at the domain, so it's still a good test. In my case, site access was geo-restricted so once admins fixed that, the URL worked and returned the file.

Comment: how did u add the cache header>

Comment: for me, its 48hours still dont see anything with my domain, shows only `Not Found`. Any idea how to go about this one?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot clear the cache for Apple's CDN in any way I've found, but you can at least make sure its right when for when it does update...

#### Confirming the Latest Version through Apple Servers

This will not clear the cache, but it will allow you to confirm that when the cache updates it will be correct.

1. Go to: https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/yourdomain.com
2. Add a ?1 or ?anything after the url. Adding any query string will make the cdn re-request the resource so you can see that it WILL be correct when the primary url is updated.

Again, this does not clear the cache for the url apple devices actually use, but it does allow you to confirm that it will be correct.

#### Development / Mode Flags for Testing

As mentioned by others, you can add the developer or managed options while in development mode:

[Apple Documentation - Associated Domains - Enable Alternate Modes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-an-associated-domain#Enable-alternate-mode-for-unreachable-servers)

Example

```
applinks:yourdomain.com?mode=developer
```

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario you could use the `developer` alternate mode when defining the associated domains entitlement for your app. The [developer alternate mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains#discussion) bypasses the CDN cache and goes directly to your server for the app association.

To do this, a query string is added to the associated domains entitlement:

`<service>:<fully qualified domain>?mode=developer`

This goes in the "Associated Domains" capability which is accessible via XCode. See more in the docs: [Adding capabilities to your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-capabilities-to-your-app)

Answer (score 1):

You can check lifetime of CDN version on apple side using :

https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/<yourdomain.com>

Then open inspector to check Response Headers :

- Age
- Cache-Control: max-age

The cache lifetime is equal to max-age - age in seconds.

So you have to wait this time and recheck with url https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/<yourdomain.com>

Answer (score -2):

You can use debug mode to get the AASA file not from apple CDN, but from your server.

`applinks:mydomain.com?mode=developer`

More info: https://github.com/NikKovIos/AASA-Universal-Links-Information/tree/main